# cx_Oracle and Lambda Layer error - aws lambda cannot locate a 64-bit oracle client library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cx-oracle, aws-lambda-layers

I created the lambda layer using cx_oracle and oracle-instantclient. Created the lambda layer and  am able import the cx_oracle but it is always gives me an error like 64-bit oracle client library is missing. below is my folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There could be several root causes of this issue.

1. Check the file structure in the AWS console. You can also try to debug the lambda by listing the files from the layer you use. Try to check the correctness of the path with - [Including library dependencies in a layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path)
   .
2. For cx_Oracle you also need to set an env var `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to the place where the libs are placed. You can update it on the lambda page in AWS console. As the layer is in `/opt` folder provide the path where the module with libs is installed.

Comment: How can we set that? LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @Aruns follow this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be set to `/opt/` + the folder you where you installed the lib files. Additionally, you may either need to `PYTHONPATH` var setting it to `/opt` or structure the files in the layer by putting the module code into `python/lib/python/site-packages`

Comment: If you can get logging output, with cx_Oracle 8, set DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL=64 before starting cx_Oracle.  The log will show where it's looking for the Oracle client libraries.